# a template trick to replace identity/std::function combo

Tags: c++, templates

Recently, i have been looking into ECS frameworks. These frameworks prefer 'data oriented' approaches rather than 'object oriented' ones. Here is the usual approach

```
class player {
public:
    uint64_t id;
    std::array<float, 3> position{ 0, 0, 0 };
    std::array<float, 2> vel{ 0, 0 };
};

std::vector<player> list_of_players;

int main()
{
    for (player p : list_of_players) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

with ECS this thing becomes like

```
struct entity{
    uint64_t id;
};

struct transform {
    std::array<float, 3> position{ 0, 0, 0 };
};
struct velocity{
    std::array<float, 2> vel{ 0, 0 };
};
std::vector<velocity> velocity_by_entity;
std::vector<transform> position_by_entity;
std::vector<entity> list_of_players;


int main()
{
    for (entity : list_of_players) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Now, user may need to process more than 1 data lets say, both velocity and position, in this case we need to provide him a projection of the data. He provides the list of types that he needs (as a template parameter)and an appropriate callback function(as parameter of 'each' function). To solve this I have seen[[1]](https://github.com/alecthomas/entityx/blob/master/entityx/Entity.h) a special trick which actually uses an identity struct for type erasure. The following is the simplified version of it.

```
template <typename ... Components>
class TypedView {
public:
    template <typename T> struct identity { typedef T type; };

    void each(typename identity<std::function<void(entity e, Components&...)>>::type f) {
        //get requested data for each entity and
        //use parameter unpacking, initializer_lists, 
        //tuples and all kind of magic to push the requested
        //data as a parameter to f 
        //call f
    }
};
int main()
{
    TypedView<transform, velocity> tv;
    tv.each([](entity e, transform& t, velocity& v) {
        //do something....
    });
    TypedView<transform> tv2;
    tv2.each([](entity e, transform& t) {
        //do something....
    });
    TypedView<velocity> tv3;
    tv3.each([](entity e, velocity& v) {
        //do something....
    });
}
```

Now my goal is to eliminate std::function and its little runtime overhead while keeping the same functionality. While browsing the repositories i have also found the solution[[2]](https://github.com/BlackMATov/ecs.hpp)  (at least i believe so) but i could't successfully create a simpflied version of it. Would someone provide an explanation and simplified version of the second solution?

//EDIT 1
removed line where function f is called directly and causing confusion
//EDIT2 tried to clarify the situation a bit more for those unfamiliar with ECS frameworks
//EDIT 3 typo

Comment: there is no erasure. `identity<T>::type` is still just `T`. I can imagine this `identity` is from before `std::type_identity` and can be useful to have a non-deduced context, but thats not how it is used in this code. I don't see what purpose it serves in this code. You can remove it and the code does the same,no?

Comment: or do you mean the type erasure that is done by `std::function`? THen its not clear what you mean with "overhead", because the "overhead" of `std::function` is just the type erasue (which is often not needed and ony then it is unnecessary overhead)

Comment: please show an example of how you want to call `each`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number lambda function will be provided by lib user and it has to contain template parameters provided to TypedView. I am fine with the current solution, i was actually wondering about the second solution provided in the link.

Comment: your second link is to the main page of some repository. Its not clear what part specifically you refer to

Comment: registry::for_joined_components function actually provides the same functionality in the second link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what purpose `identity` serves in the code. It looks similar to `std::type_identity` which can be used to create a non-deduced context. This is not what happens in the code.

If you want type erasure of callables, `std::function` is just the right tool. However, from the posted code it is not clear whether type erasure is needed at all (could be if for example `each` must be one and the same function for any type of callable, if this is the case is not clear from the posted code).

When no type erasure is needed and `each` itself can be a template then something like this can be used:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

struct entity{
    uint64_t id;
};

struct transform {
    std::array<float, 3> position{ 0, 0, 0 };
};
struct velocity{
    std::array<float, 2> vel{ 0, 0 };
};
std::vector<velocity> velocity_by_entity(3);
std::vector<transform> position_by_entity(3);
std::vector<entity> list_of_players{{1},{2},{3}};

template <typename Entity,typename... Component,typename F>
void for_each(const std::vector<Entity>& entities,F f,const Component&...comp) {
    std::size_t i=0;
    for (const auto& entity : entities) {
        f(entity,comp[i]...);
        ++i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    for_each(list_of_players,[](const auto& player,const auto& vel,const auto& pos){
        std::cout << player.id << " velocity[0]: " << vel.vel[0] << " position[0]: " << pos.position[0] << "\n";
    },velocity_by_entity,position_by_entity);
}
```

[output](https://godbolt.org/z/crbdaW4nd):

```
1 velocity[0]: 0 position[0]: 0
2 velocity[0]: 0 position[0]: 0
3 velocity[0]: 0 position[0]: 0
```

Note that this is not a "trick" and that there is also no type erasure (as mentioned above I assume its not needed). Only to get nicer error messages you may want to add a `requires` or concept to check that `F` can be called with the given arguments.

To reiterate: It might be that the code in the OP is subject to the rather common misunderstanding that `std::function` would be useful whenever you need to pass a callable to a function. This is not true. `std::function` is useful for type erased callables. It is not obvious whether the posted code does need type erased callables. If not `std::function` can be just removed. If it does, then `std::function` is the right tool. The `identity` serves no apparent purpose in the code.

Comment: 1-first guy tries to protect himself against type deduction problems, 2-second guy actually using your obvious answer. I have just realized it, no tricks.

Comment: @eserbilal there are not type "deduction problems". Not in the code you have shown. The member `each` itself is no a template, nothing is being deduced

Comment: To clarify your function's template parameters/parameters usage requirements, I'd add (in case of C++20) a requires expression that validates that the function type `F` is a good fit.

Comment: @CoralKashri good point. I wanted to add a note but then forgot about it